# iOS Status Bar not inheriting Navigation Bar Color - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am completely new to iOS programming and can't figure out how to get my status bar to inherit the color of my navigation bar. I managed to get the status bar text color to change but no luck on the background color yet.

I've searched for similar questions and tried many different things but I just can't figure it out. How can I get the status bar to match the pink of my nav bar?

Thanks!

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: try embedding your view controller in UINavigationbar and change the navigationcontroller's navigation bar barTintColor property to the color you want to set.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed to do. Appreciate your help!